# Temporarily disable all kernel logging?

Tags: kernel, logs, gentoo, syslog

I know it's generally a bad idea to disable all kernel logging and in any other situation I would not be attempting to do this, but for my current applications having a period of time where the kernel does no logging would be ideal. If there a way to completely disable kernel logging? I'm trying to do this on a gentoo linux system

Note, the system is not equipped with `rsyslog` or `syslog-nd` it is purely a `syslog(8)` system

Comment: Do you really want to disable all logging, or is output to a particular tty or serial port causing trouble?

Comment: I actually want to disable all logging. I was thinking of running a `while true` bash script that just invokes `dmesg -C` and clearing the kernel buffer while my other program takes place

Comment: Does `sysctl -w kernel.printk=0 7 0 0` help? A dangerous thing to do indeed.

Comment: Nevermind, I realized you actually want to stop the messages going to syslog. Hmm. Sorry, don't know of a way. Maybe killing `klogd`, which is a separate program in the classic syslog setup, but not in the more modern ones?

Comment: Doesn't look like killing that worked either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that stumbles across this, using `killall syslogd` did the job!